Cant find the fingerprint option on ubuntu 24.04
It detects when I use lsusb but can't run fprintd-enroll
fprintd-enroll
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
sudo systemctl start fprintd && sudo systemctl status fprintd
● fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-07-08 15:22:30 IST; 3s ago
       Docs: man:fprintd(1)
   Main PID: 90113 (fprintd)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 9114)
     Memory: 1.6M (peak: 2.5M)
        CPU: 72ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/fprintd.service
             └─90113 /usr/libexec/fprintd

Jul 08 15:22:30 bhanu-vardhan-reddy-Vostro-3500 systemd[1]: Starting fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Jul 08 15:22:30 bhanu-vardhan-reddy-Vostro-3500 fprintd[90113]: Creating TOD wrapper for goodix-tod (Goodix Fingerprint Sensor 53xc) driver
Jul 08 15:22:30 bhanu-vardhan-reddy-Vostro-3500 systemd[1]: Started fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.


Most of the fingerprint scanners don't work in Ubuntu because the manufacturers only shared the proprietary device drivers with Microsoft but not with the Linux kernel.

What is the model of your laptop?

I have exactly the same problem. And here are the logs via this command: journalctl -xe | grep fprintd
Sep 25 10:05:30 mathis-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
░░ The unit fprintd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Sep 25 10:08:45 mathis-HP-ZBook-15-G5 sudo[5076]:   mathis : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/mathis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start fprintd
Sep 25 10:08:45 mathis-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: Starting fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit fprintd.service has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit fprintd.service has begun execution.
Sep 25 10:08:45 mathis-HP-ZBook-15-G5 systemd[1]: Started fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.


I had the same problem. I updated to Ubuntu 24.04 from 23.10 and fingerprint worked. But after some update (like month ago) it disappears and it looks like the fingerprint login option is not available anymore.
For me it helps to downgrade the driver in Firmware Updater - Prometheus Fingerprint reader (from 10.01.40xxxx to 10.01.3478575).
Lenovo ThinkPad P14s gen 2i (Intel version)
Firmware version: N34ET63W (1.63)
